# SFTP does not work for one user, SSH does work

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-12.04, sftp

I can login with password via `root` and `user1`
I can login with Filezilla via `root` but not `user1`

Here is end of Filezilla log

```
Trace:  Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
Command:    Pass: *********
Trace:  Sent password
Trace:  Access denied
Error:  Authentication failed.
Error:  Critical error
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

`root` and `user1` have same password.
I tried to re-enter password.

I can login via ssh as `user1`

It is typical cloud server and I never had such problem before.

I have no idea why I can't use Filezilla with that user of that machine.

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

**PS**
/var/log/auth.log

Nov 24 23:33:07 secure sshd[5811]: Failed password for invalid user  user1 from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port XXXXX ssh2

**PS2**

I login with SFTP in Ubuntu 10.04, 13.10 but not 12.04
I created another virtual machine and set password for user1 with passwd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. It was Filezilla fault.

I clicked "Copy" button to copy `root` user settings. Then I re-entered password but it does not help.
When I created just "new site" in Filezilla manually then it started working.
(re-entering correct values does not help)
Seems to be Filezilla internal bug

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same problem for one particular user account myself. Changing the user's password somehow resolved it... still scratching my head as to why!

I was just using the Quickconnect option in FileZilla to test this with before and after.

One other note which might prove useful is that I observed the user's home directory and contents were owned by root (long story). Although fixing this did not allow me to log in, the FileZilla bug mentioned above might have somehow been at play here also, so the act of changing the user's password may have gotten around that after the original problem was resolved... who knows!

Comment: Filezilla bug. May consume lots of time.